# Householder Transformation and sign fixation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

In my book it is said that if we have a Householder Transformation:

$H\vec{x}$,

$H=I-\frac{2\vec u \vec u^T}{\vec{u}^T \vec{u}}$

then the vector $\vec{u}$ of the $H$ is $\vec{u}=\vec{x} \pm \left\| x \right \|_2\vec{e_1}$

And usually in order to fix the sign we use the function $sign(x)$ like this:

$$\vec{u}= \vec{x}+sign(x_1)\left\| x \right \|_2\vec{e_1}$$

My question now is what happens when $x_1=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Then $\vec x$ and $\vec e_1$  are orthogonal, both variants are equally good, you can chose the sign any way you want, for instance by setting ${\rm sign}(0)=1$.

For numerical stability the cases $|x_1|<\frac13\|x\|_2$ are not that interesting, you could use the positive sign for $x_1\ge-\frac13\|x\|_2$. ($\frac13$ is an example of a small positive number, there is no special meaning.) What this is meant to say is that there does not happen anything dangerous if the sign flips "the wrong way" around $x_1\approx 0$.